# Apache Virtualhost Redirect HTTPS non-www to HTTPS www not working

Tags: apache-2.4, https, redirect

I'm having an issue with apache. I would like to redirect:
http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com - ok
http://example.com to https://www.example.com - ok
https://example.com to https://www.example.com - not redirected

This is the setting of my vhost.conf in Apache:

```
<NameVirtualHost *:80>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    ErrorLog /home/example/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/example/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin user@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html
    ErrorLog /home/example/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/example/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

"RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off" has no effect since it is already on port 443